# Как преобразовать из str в byte правильно

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как строку '0xa061' преобразовать в байты(именно в таком формате) - b'\xa0\x61' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
text = '0xa061'
print(bytes.fromhex(text[2:]))
```

Comment: Буквально перед вами нашел ответ, но ставлю вам лайк + Ответ вопроса))
Спасибо))